# Need to use Applescript to select items in a folder that are a SPECIFIC filename length (with other details); XXXXX.png

Tags: applescript

I need a script that can select all items in a folder that meet the following criteria:

1. Names use 5.3 convention (i.e. "XB2F6.jpg")
2. Names cannot contain an underscore

I have no idea where to start. Is there a standard way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Your two criteria in the question do not include the one criteria in your question title regarding filename length; unless "5.3 convention" is what this refers to, but you should explain what that means.  Currently, I have no idea what files you want selected except that files shouldn't contain an underscore.

Comment: "5.3" is a standard that I was hoping would be understood. It refers to the original DOS "8.3" convention which dictated that all filenames on a system were required to contain a maximum eight characters with a 3 character extension (i.e. "laptopxl.jpg"). Using this rule, our filenames all have five characters with a three character extension.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename

Comment: So you just want to select all files in a folder that have five characters in the filename plus a three-character extension (no underscores) ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Finder"
    set _W to a reference to front Finder window
    if not (_W exists) then return false

    set fs to every file in _W
    set gs to {}

    repeat with f in fs
        set filename to f's name
        set extension to f's name extension
        if the filename's length = 9 and ¬
            the extension's length = 3 and ¬
            the filename does not contain "_" then ¬
            set end of gs to f's contents
    end repeat

    select gs
    activate
end tell
```